# Find the dimension in the subset

Tags: linear-algebra

Find  the dimension of the subset of all polynomials {q(t)} of $P^3$ such that q(0) = 0 .

Thanks in advance

in my work, I think the equation of $P^3$ is like the $P_0$+$P_1q$ + $P_2q^2$+$P_3q^3$
as q(0) = 0, but I am not sure how is the matrix  in these polynomials
as the maximum dimension of $P^3$ is 4 I think.

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  First is the notion of *subspace* of a vector space.  All of $P^3$ is a vector space, so to discuss the dimension of a "subset of all polynomials" we need to know it is a subspace of that vector space.  Second is the notion of *dimension*, which is the size of a basis for a vector space (or of a subspace).

Answer (score 3):

A polynomial of degree (at most) $3$ [which is what the notation $P^3$ usually refers to] has form $$q(t)=a+bt+ct^2+dt^3.$$ These form a vector space of dimension $4$ over the reals (or some other field such as complexes-- you didn't specify).

I think your attempt is too complicated. The subset you mention is given by $q(0)=0,$ i.e. by $a=0.$ So you're left with arbitrary $b,c,d$ and so dimension is $3.$